# Is union of disjoint path-connected sets not path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is the following true:

> The union of disjoint path-connected sets is not path-connected.

Comment: I don't understand the context: $[0,1)\cup [1,2]$ is path connected...

Comment: Pedantic remark: If at least one of the two is empty, the union is path-connected. And even for nonempty sets, the union can be path-connected, consider $[0,1] \cup (1,2] = [0,2]$. For nonempty sets, you need a topological condition, e.g. they're closed or open.

Comment: @DanielFischer : May be the question is using the topology for the disjoint union?

Comment: If by union, you mean topological sum, then this space is not path-connected in any case, regardless of the spaces involved (as long as none of them is empty).

Comment: @JustinYoung Clare to clarify?

Comment: I don't know if you mean path-connected subspaces of a larger space and the set theoretic union, or maybe the disjoint union of arbitrary spaces. A set can't be path-connected, it needs a topology. If it's the first then the above is a counterexample. If it's the second, it's pretty much trivial as it won't even be connected. (Ignoring the empty space).

Answer (score 3):

You have to require that the sets are open and non-empty to make the statement interresting (otherwise we could just take one path-connected set and partition it and disprove the statement).

Assuming that makes the statement equivalent to if path-connectedness implies connectednes for open sets, and yes that's true.

Assume that an open set is path-connected and assume we can decompose it as union of two disjoint open non-empty sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. Then we can select two points $x_1\in\Omega_1$ and $x_2\in\Omega_2$ (since they're non-empty).

Now consider a path $\gamma$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ that is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to the set and $\gamma(0)=x_1$ and $\gamma(1)=x_2$. Now we consider $t=\sup_{\gamma(\tau)\in\Omega_1}\tau$. Now for an neighborhood $V$ of $\gamma(\tau)$ there should be an neigborhood of $\tau$ such that $\gamma(t)\in V$ in that neighborhood. But as any neigborhood of $\tau$ contains points that maps to both $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ we have a contradiction.